# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException, Java scanner

Tags: java

I know there are a couple of questions on this topic, I just couldn't find an answer which I understand.

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Train
{
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter 4 integers ");
   System.out.println("Please enter the speed of train 1: ");
   int v1 = scan.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Please enter the time of train 1: ");
   int t1 = scan.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Please enter the speed of train 2: ");
   int v2 = scan.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Please enter the time of train 2: ");
   int t2 = scan.nextInt();

   int d1 = v1*t1;
   int d2 = v2*t2;

   System.out.println(Math.abs(d1-d2));
 }
}
```

which produces the following log:

```
Please enter 4 integers 
Please enter the speed of train 1: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Train.main(Train.java:9)
```

Please help me find the error and fix it. Thanks in advance!
Uri

Comment: works for me, what input are you using?

Comment: online IDE. now it works cause I use a regular IDE

Answer (score 1):

The `Scanner` throws `java.util.NoSuchElementException` in case it encounters end of input when trying to read next token.
You can reproduce it by using ^D (Linux) or ^Z (Windows)

Also it will occur if you close the input stream before scanner can read from it.

You don't explain how you run the program (IDE? console?) but looks like it occurs on the first read and at that time (my guess) the System.in is already closed.

Comment: I used an online IDE once I switched to Eclipse or BlueJ it stopped showing the error message. Thx!